# How to check rails has_many records contain specified record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have User and Technology table. My association is `User has_many technologies and not belongs_to user`. I need to check whether the user contains particular technology or not

**Example:**

```
@technology = Technology.find_by_url "some_url"
@user = User.find params[:id]
```

Now i need to check whether the user has particular technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) can do this for you.

```
@user.technologies.exists?(@technology.id)
```